# iPhone event when about to rotate?

Tags: iphone, events, rotation

In my app I'd like to do some processing before my view rotates. Is there an event that fires just before rotation takes place?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out these methods of UIViewController:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
// Notifies when rotation begins, reaches halfway point and ends.
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;


- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;

// Faster one-part variant, called from within a rotating animation block, for additional animations during rotation.
// A subclass may override this method, or the two-part variants below, but not both.
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);

// Slower two-part variant, called from within a rotating animation block, for additional animations during rotation.
// A subclass may override these methods, or the one-part variant above, but not both.
- (void)willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation; // The rotating header and footer views are offscreen.
- (void)willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration; // A this point, our view orientation is set to the new orientation.
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of events in UIViewController that are triggered during a rotation.  The following two trigger before the rotation:

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

"Sent to the view controller just before the user interface begins rotating."

```
- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

"Sent to the view controller before performing a one-step user interface rotation."